# Rolling a 20 sided dice n number of times, and print the values in a array - java

Tags: java, arrays, dice

I am trying to make a Java program that make n number of random values between 1-20, and put them in an array. My program so far is:

```
public class bias{
    public static void main(String[] as){
        for (int n = 10; 0 < n; n--){
            int[] values;
            values = new int[n];
            int b = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 1;
            values[n--] = b;
        }
        System.out.println(values.length);      
    }
}
```

But I get an error when I compile it:

```
C:\javas>javac bias.java
bias.java:9 error: cannot find symbol
              System.out.printLn<values.length>;
  symbol: variable values 
  location: class bias
1 error
```

I can't seem to understand and debug, what my problem is?

Comment: Don't you mean: `values[n] = b`?

Answer (score 3):

`int[] values;` should be out side of for loop.

do like below

```
 int[] values = new int[10];    
 for (int n = 10; 0 < n; n--){           
           int b = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 1;
           values[n] =b;
 }
```

Remove  `int[] values; values = new int[n];`  from your for loop. It will create new array for each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You declared your values object inside the `for` loop, thus it is only available inside it.
Move it outside of the loop.

I recommend taking a look at variable scopes: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

I think what you want is:

```
int[] values = new int[10];    
for (int n = 10; 0 < n; n--){           
    values[n] = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 1;
} 
System.out.println(values.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `values` array is simply out of scope when you try to print its length. Its scope is limited to the `for` code block.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable Outside the loop

Since you have declare varible `int[] values;` inside the loop so this varible have scope inside the loop and will not be visible outside the loop so declare it outside so it's scope become full program .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution what you need to do read the number n from console 
Create a array of that size and go on adding numbers to it.
Then u can iterate over the array to get all values.

```
public class bias{
    public static void main(String[] as){

        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter number n: ");
        String s1=dis.readLine ();
        int num = int n1=Integer.parseInt (s1);
        int[] values = new int[num];
        for (int n = 0; n < num; n++){
            int b = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 1;
            values[n] = b;
        }
        System.out.println(values.length);      
        for (int n = 0; n < num; n++){
            System.out.println(values[n]);      
        }
    }
}
```